# Render in django can't passing an argument

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

i'm new in django and i'm trying to create an application that user can change his/her password based on his/her id. So far is good, but when i'm trying to passing an argument from my views.py, there is a trouble that an argument can't passing to the html template.

This is my views:

```
def tambah_user(request, template_name='form_user.html'):
    if 'username' in request.session:
        username = User.objects.all()
        data = {}
        data['object_list'] = username
        if request.method == 'POST':
            user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
            profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)

            if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
                user = user_form.save()
                user.set_password(user.password)
                user.save()
                profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
                profile.user = user
                profile.save()
                return redirect('manajemen_user')
            else:
                print user_form.errors, profile_form.errors
        else:
            user_form = UserForm()
            profile_form = UserProfileForm()

        return render(request, template_name,
                {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form, 'data': data},)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/simofa/login')
```

with that code, `data` can't passing to the html template.

when i changed render like this

```
return render(request, template_name,data)
```

it works properly, but user_form and profile_form isn't passing to the template.

My question:

1. Can i passing `data, user_form, profile_form` together to the template?
2. if can, how? if not, is there any other way ?

I really appreciate your input. so please help me. Thanks ^__^

Comment: You haven't said what is wrong with your original code.

Comment: sorry, i have updated my question sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The render statement isn't expecting a trailing comma like when you're defining a tuple, which is most likely what's causing the error, however your code could use some refactoring....

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

# assuming you're using your own form here for some reason...
from .forms import UserForm

# use the login_required decorator instead of manually checking for the session
@login_required
def tambah_user(request, template_name='form_user.html'):
    # `users` just makes more sense here for the variable name
    users = User.objects.all()

    # no need for the extra if clause to create unbound forms
    user_form = UserForm(request.POST or None)
    profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()

            # you need to pass in the raw password here,
            # otherwise you're hashing the already hashed password
            # if you were to be editing an instance
            user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data('password'))
            user.save()
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            profile.save()

            # you need to use reverse by name to do this
            return redirect(reverse('manajemen_user'))
        else:
            print user_form.errors, profile_form.errors

    # notice I have omitted the trailing comma after the context
    # dictionary
    return render(request, template_name, {'user_form': user_form,
        'profile_form': profile_form, 'data': users})
```

I hope you've read the [documentation for authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/) in Django, because there are built-in forms and views to do pretty much everything you'd ever need to do for users instead of writing your own.

Comment: thank you for your input sir. but its seems to be no changes sir. the data isn't passing to the html template sir. but when i write  "return render(request, template_name, data)" it works sir.

Comment: There must be something in your view that you're not showing in your question, because there's no reason at all why `data` as per my example wouldn't be passed to the template, nor in your original code.

Comment: No sir, i've showed all of my view function sir and my question is only about why data can't passing to the html template. 
`username = User.objects.all()`
        `data = {}`
        `data['object_list'] = username`

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking. Are you not getting any objects? Are you sure you have users to query? Are you getting an exception? If you print the value of `users` in my sample or `data` in yours, what do you get?

Comment: hai @brandon. im very grateful for your answer. i've wrong in my concept about render. the `data` variable have contain in the list {} and i don't see when i put it in render. now I have solved my problem. Thank you. 
your answer is right. sory for all ^__^